# What GCP product to use to run Docker container exposing a range of UDP ports to public internet

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, udp

I am confused about which GCP product to use such that I can run a Docker container e.g. like "docker run -p 5001-5110:5001-5110/udp hunter_ctrl_standalone:latest -s foo". The container will use ca. 2 GB of RAM, 1 CPU. No load balancing needed.

It seems that Cloud Run is for HTTP(s) workloads only. GKE also looks like more for HTTP(s) workloads. Container on Compute Engine using Container Optimized OS (COS) does seem to do the trick, but then again according to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations it is not possible to automatically operate the container through an API (only console plus gloud).

Do I miss a possibility? Is there a good overview for GCP runtime environments with their pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you’re trying to gather some information about different GCP products and where to run your deployments, and the pros of them.

I found this StackOverflow question answer [1] that I think you might find interesting.

---

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697049/what-is-the-difference-between-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine/49950687#49950687

Answer (score 0):

**AppEngine** sounds good for me. You can set forward port on app.yaml file:

*forwarded_ports:*
*Optional. You can forward ports from your instance (HOST_PORT) to the Docker container (CONTAINER_PORT). If you only specify a PORT, then App Engine assumes that it is the same port on the host and the container. By default, both TCP and UDP traffic are forwarded. Traffic must be directly addressed to the target instance's IP address rather than over the appspot.com domain or your custom domain.*

*Port forwarding* allows for direct connections to the Docker container on your instances. This traffic can travel over any protocol.
[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding][1]

Although using a VMs with Container Optimized OS sounds good as well, AppEngine is Platform as Service and requires fewer things to do